# Can not assign to read only property 'navigator' of object '#<DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope>'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I facing error **Can not assign to read only property 'navigator' of object '#'** while my app is in debugging mode.
I gone through whole code but not able to find out reason where is pitfall also i didn't get solution of it. My parent class implementation is

```
class MainPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
          initialRoute={{id: 'SplashPage', name: 'SplashPage'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          configureScene={(route) => {
            if (route.sceneConfig) {
              return route.sceneConfig;
            }
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
      }} />
    );
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;

    if (routeId === 'SplashPage') {
      return (
        <SplashPage
          navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
      );
    }


    if (routeId === 'Login') {
      return (
        <Login
          navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />
      );
    }

    return this.noRoute(navigator);
  }

  noRoute(navigator) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Please check you Navigation Logic</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

module.exports = MainPage;
```

My child class implementation is ,

```
class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '',password:'' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          navigator={this.props.navigator}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar style={styles.container}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
          } />
    );
  }
  validateLogin() {

    if(!Validators.validateOnlyText(this.state.username)) {
      alert('User ID cannot be blank');
      return;
    }

    if(!Validators.validateOnlyText(this.state.password)) {
      alert('Password cannot be blank');
      return;
    }

    var webServiceName=WebserviceHelper.Constants.POST_AUTHENTICATION;
    var valuesJson= { "UserId" : this.state.username,  "Password" : this.state.password };
    WebserviceHelper.postValues(webServiceName, valuesJson, this);
  }

  postWebCallback(webResponse){
    navigator.parentNavigator.replace({
      id: 'Home',
      passProps: {
            'userId': this.state.username,
            'userNo' : this.state.webResponse.userNo

    });
module.exports = Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had got this problem also. What the compiler doesn't like is this

```
ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
```

on the Navigator tag.

I have resolved it by changing the `navigator` word to `thisNavigator`, and declaring it outside the scope with the `var` declaration.